# Как преобразовать curl с параметром --data в fetch с методом get?

Tags: javascript, api

необходимо преобразовать:

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/feed/posts/ --data "page=1" -H "Authorization: Token a96a3545bb566272f0fdfb405a0cccb7173da660"
```

в fetch с методом get. Каким образом я могу передать туда параметр page? я пробовал вот этот [сайт](http://kigiri.github.io/fetch/), но он возвращает мне fetch с методом post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/feed/posts/?page=1', { 
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        });
```

Таким образом можно отправить GET запрос через fetch. Так же еще можно воспользоваться async/await.

```
async function fetchSomething() {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/feed/posts/?page=1', { 
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        })

        const result = await response.json();
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Все таки я бы добавил, что параметры в самом URL'e не должны хардкодиться. Можно воспользоваться [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) для вот этой части `?page=1`